Property vector in Weaviate
I have created a schema in weaviate and trying to figure out if a vector has been generated for a property.
entityClass := &models.Class{
    Class:       classEntity,
    Description: "A generic class to store various entities",
    Properties: []*models.Property{
        {
            Name:        propertyName,
            DataType:    []string{"text"},
            Description: "Name of the entity",
        },
        {
            Name:            propertyDescription,
            DataType:        []string{"text"},
            Description:     "Description of the entity",
            IndexSearchable: &indexSearchableFalse,
        },
        {
            Name:        propertyPossibleValues,
            DataType:    []string{"object[]"},
            Description: "Possible values for the entity",
            NestedProperties: []*models.NestedProperty{
                {
                    Name:        propertyName, // THIS SHOULD BE VECTORIZED - HOW????
                    DataType:    []string{"text"},
                    Description: "Name of the possible value",
                },
            },
        },
    },
    Vectorizer: "text2vec-transformers",
}

I have read the documentation (https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/api/rest#tag/objects/POST/objects) and although as I understood it is feasible, I can't find a way to achieve it.
Note that if I call the following endpoint: http://localhost:8080/v1/objects?include=vector, a vector is returned but on the class level as you can see below:
{
        "class": "Entity",
        "creationTimeUnix": 1727463789740,
        "id": "9c5aadb9-aa45-475d-8b6b-63ca8ffbd0c8",
        "lastUpdateTimeUnix": 1727463789740,
        "properties": {
            "description": "It indicates uncertainty, lack of information, or the discovery of new information.",
            "name": "InfoTest2",
            "possibleValues": [
                {
                    "name": "notAvailable",  
                },
            ]
        },
        "vector": [
            0.0278321,
            0.006750059,
            .............
        ],
        "vectorWeights": null
    }

The above proves that the connection between the vectorizer and weaviate is successful, so it is only a matter of calling the API with the right parameters.

Duda from Weaviate here!
This is the actual vector of your object. So considering you never passed a vector when you created that object, it was generated by your transformers model.
this endpoint http://localhost:8080/v1/objects?include=vector will yield all the objects in your cluster.
So this is a list of objects, and one of the properties is the class it belongs to.
Let me know if this helps :)
